# setSupportActionBar and toolbar.inflateMenu don't work together?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

Calling `setSupportActionBar` and inflating a menu as follows results in not showing the menu:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        myToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:title="Test"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I know the alternative is to use the traditional `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.
Other alternative is to remove the line `setSupportActionBar`, but I need to show displayHomeAsUpEnabled.

Is it possible to use both `myToolbar.inflateMenu()` *and* `setSupportActionBar` simultaneously or is it incompatible?

Comment: You don't need `displayHomeAsUpEnabled` if you're using a Toolbar - it has its own navigation button APIs.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks, but then what should I use? Bear in mind this activity is not using Navigation from Architecture Components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `setSupportActionBar()`, yes, you must solely use the ActionBar APIs and directly manipulating the Toolbar, be it by adding a Menu or other changes, are not supported.

If you don't want to use the ActionBar APIs, then don't call `setSupportActionBar` and use the Toolbar APIs directly (those are what the ActionBar APIs call anyways, so the Toolbar APIs are a superset of the ActionBar APIs already).

Toolbars have their own APIs for handling the navigation button (which is what `displayHomeAsUpEnabled` plugs into).

You can take advantage of this by adding the Up icon to your Toolbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

Then you can get a callback on when the button is pressed by setting a click listener:

```
myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
  // handle the navigation button
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately nothing prevents us from trying to combine existing APIs with newer APIs. There're still lots of SO questions/answers and even the offical Android docs stating to use setSupportActionBar+setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled to show the up button in a Toolbar.

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action

If this isn't the recommended approach anymore it would be nice to have that clarified in the docs. I mean, what's the point of having a Toolbar and using setSupportActionBar+setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled if there's already what you explained in this answer.